# Automating producing ggplot in same dataframe

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have a dataset that has first column as periods in date format and then about 50 columns. All columns have the same scale and are numbers. I'm trying to plot two columns at a time lets say Column 1 and Column 2 by period and then Column 3 and Column 4 etc until I run out of iteration.

The function I wrote, won't work. It doesn't give me any error but produces no output. When I run the code outside of the loop it works.

Reproducible sample below

```
H<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE)))  
H$Date<-seq(as.Date('2001-03-31'),by='quarter',length=10)
H<-H[,c(11,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)]



 plotmebabe<-function(a){
  for (i in 2:length(a)){
    ggplot(data=a,aes(x=Date)) + 
      geom_line(aes(y=a[,i]),color="blue",size=2)+
      geom_line(aes(y=a[,i+1]),color="pink",size=2) +
      ylab(label="This is Y axis")+
      xlab("This is X axis")+
      ggtitle("Hello")+ 
      theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))
  }}
```

Comment: A reproducible example should reproduce your problem.

Comment: amended the error. should reproduce the issue\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ggplot object is only drawn with it is actually print()-ed. When you type something at the interactive command line, the results are implicitly print()-ed. When you run code inside of for loop, this implicit printing doesn't happen. you need to actually call print() on the object to trigger the drawing.

Here's an updated version (fixing other mistakes as well)

```
 plotmebabe<-function(a){       
  for (i in 2:(ncol(a)-1)){
    print(ggplot(data=a,aes(x=Date)) + 
      geom_line(aes_string(y=names(a)[i]),color="blue",size=2)+
      geom_line(aes_string(y=names(a)[i+1]),color="pink",size=2) +
      ylab(label="This is Y axis")+
      xlab("This is X axis")+
      ggtitle("Hello")+ 
      theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold")))
  }}
plotmebabe(H)
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems to work well. How do I make it plot C1 and C2 and then C3 and C4 etc. Its currently plotting C1 and C2 and then C2 and C3 and then C3 and C4 etc. I don't want C2 and C3. I guess I could just ignore those plots

Comment: use `for (i in seq(2, ncol(a)-1, by=2)) {`

Comment: Thanks - now only if I could add a legend that I can customize - i could call one series -"Apples" and the other "Oranges"

Comment: move the color= into the aes_string and set the values to "apples" and "oranges". Then add `+scale_color_manual(values=c("apples"="blue","oranges"="pink")`

Comment: I get an error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'apples' not found" . I moved it inside aes "geom_line(aes_string(y=names(a)[i],color="apples",size=2))"

Comment: As, sorry about that, If you want to use a literal string in an `aes_string()`, use `geom_line(aes_string(y=names(a)[i],color=shQuote("apples")),size=2)`

Comment: this gives me a diff error "Error in print(ggplot(data = a, aes(x = Period)) + geom_line(aes_string(y = names(a)[i],  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator" also, the specified colors don't show up.

Comment: There must be some other typo there. The error is insufficient to identify the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should open a new question since you seem to be having a different problem now.

Comment: Its fine - i made it work there was a parenthesis missing. Why does the title of the legend show up as "apples" and not just "legend"

Comment: ok found a fix, included legend title in the color manual command